# How can I send an MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP POST and avoid having the \ character escaped?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, yaml

Im using an API ( MadMiMi's Mailer API, specifically) that requires that I perform an HTTP post and send a YAML string as one of the posted variables.

My attempt to execute the POST is working - that is to say - the POST is complete and is received at the API end.   The issue is that the `\n` elements in the YAML string is having the `\` escaped so that instead of

```
...\n...
```

it's being posted as

```
...\\n...
```

Maming the YAML string invalid in terms of the expected syntax.

The YAML string should look like this:

```
--- \nvar1:somedatahere\nvar2:someotherdatahere\n
```

but what is being received is:

```
--- \\nvar1:somedatahere\\nvar2:someotherdatahere\\n
```

My question is how to get the POST request to NOT escape the `\` character?

I've tried using `%5c`, and the `Chr()` code for the `\` character and also tried adding/removing:

```
httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

just to see if any noticeable difference is produced by its presence or absence, but no real change at all.  (I have that line removed now though as I'm almost certain it isn't something I need in the use case).

here is the complete post segment of my code that Im working with:

```
Dim data, httpRequest, postResponse

data = "username=*************"
data = data & "&api_key=******************"
data = data & "&promotion_name=*******"
data = data & "&cc=emailaddress1@emailaddress1.com"
data = data & "&recipient=emailaddress2@emailaddress2.com"
data = data & "&subject=My Subject Line Here"
data = data & "&from=emailaddress3@emailaddress3.com"
data = data & "&body=--- \nvar1:"& myvariable1 & "\nvar2:"& myvariable2 & "\n"

Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
httpRequest.Open "POST", "https://api.madmimi.com/mailer", False

httpRequest.Send data
postResponse = httpRequest.ResponseText
```

Comment: Did you try using literal newlines instead of the escape sequence `\n`? `"&body=--- " & vbLf & "var1:" & ...`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  thanks for cleaning up my post/question -- sorry about the formatting issues.   I tried vbLf and also tried vbCrLf, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `data` within double quotes seems to fix the issue.

```
data = """" & data & """"
httpRequest.Send data
```

(Also had to use `httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to test this)

From [Wikipedia page for YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=YAML#Syntax),

> Strings (scalars) are ordinarily unquoted, but may be enclosed in
>   double-quotes ( " ), or single-quotes ( ' ). Within double-quotes,
>   special characters may be represented with C-style escape sequences
>   starting with a backslash ( \ ).

you can check using the online parser here : http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/